# Unit test: Can't receive async

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing

I am practice async/await in react.

In this case I wrote the function inside **NavList.js**.

When I run **npm run watch**, It shows message:

> This should be seen:    10

It is success, but when I do the unit test, I got nothing, only the pass message on terminal.

> PASS  resources/assets/js/test/navList.test.js

**How can I receive async/await at unit test?**

---

**NavList.js**

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  // test async
  function resolveAfter2Seconds(x) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(x);
        }, 2000);
    });
  }
  async function runAsync() {
    var waitForTime = await resolveAfter2Seconds(10);
    console.log('This should be seen:    ',waitForTime); // 10
  }
  runAsync(); 
}
```

**NavList.test.js**

```
it.only('function setArticleGroup() ', function () {
  let app = shallow(<NavList sieve="info" />);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function inside the constructor would be hard to test, so I'm moving them to class methods.

```
class TestClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    // test async
    this.runAsync = this.runAsync.bind(this);
    this.runAsync();
  }
  resolveAfter2Seconds(x) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(x);
      }, 2000);
    });
  }
  async runAsync() {
    return await this.resolveAfter2Seconds(10);
  }
}
```

The issue with your test is that it is not a test at all. You have not written any assertions for it to test against.

Since we should have a value to test against, we are returning the value from `runAsync` function.

```
it.only('function setArticleGroup() ', async function () {
  const app = shallow(<NavList sieve="info" />);
  const result = await app.instance().runAsync();
  expect(result).to.equal(10);
});
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply. But when I do exactly as you said, it got error message:      Invalid Chai property: should      at Error (native)     > 224 |         expect(result).should.equal(10);

Comment: If I comment line 224, then I get this error:    console.error node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29
      Error: Cross origin null forbidden

Comment: @jimmy Oh! You were using Chai. I was going for Mocha. See my updated answer